# Creating a generic conversion function

Tags: c++

I have a `ResourceManager` which takes in classes of type `Resource`. `Resource` is a parent class of other classes such as `ShaderProgram`, `Texture`, `Mesh` and even `Camera` who are completely unrelated to one another.

Suffice it to say, the `ResourceManager` works. But there is one thing that is very tedious and annoying, and that's when I retrieve the objects from the `ResourceManager`. Here is the problem:

In order to get an object from `ResourceManager` you call either of these functions:

```
static Resource* get(int id);
static Resource* get(const std::string &name);
```

The first function checks one `std::unordered_map` by an integer id; whereas the second function checks another `std::unordered_map` by the name that is manually given by the client. I have two versions of these functions for flexibility sakes because there are times where we don't care what the object contained within ResourceManager is (like `Mesh`) and there are times where we do care about what it is (like `Camera` or `ShaderProgram`) because we may want to retrieve the said objects by name rather than id.

Either way, both functions return a pointer to a `Resource`. When you call the function, it's as easy as something like:

```
rm::get("skyboxShader");
```

Where `rm` is just a `typedef` of `ResourceManager` since the class is static (all members/functions are static). The problem though is that the `rm::get(..)` function returns a `Resource*`, and not the child class that was added to the `ResourceManager` to begin with. So, in order to solve this problem I have to do a manual type conversion so that I can get `ShaderProgram*` instead of `Resource*`. I do it like this:

```
auto s = static_cast<ShaderProgram*>(rm::get(name));
```

So, everytime I want to access a `Resource` I have to insert the type I want to actually get into the `static_cast`. This is problematic insofar that everytime someone needs to access a `Resource` they have to type convert it. So, naturally I created a function, and being that ShaderProgram is the subject here, thus:

```
ShaderProgram* Renderer::program(const std::string &name)
{
    auto s = static_cast<ShaderProgram*>(rm::get(name));

    return s;
}
```

This function is static, and `ResourceManager` is a static class so the two go well hand-in-hand. This is a nice helper function and it works effectively and my program renders the result just fine. The problem is what I have to do when I'm dealing with other `Resource`s; that means for every `Resource` that exists, there has to be a type-conversion function to accommodate it. Now THAT is annoying. Isn't there a way I can write a generic type-conversion function something like this?

```
auto Renderer::getResource(classTypeYouWant T, const std::string &name)
{
    auto s = static_cast<T*>(rm::get(name));

    return s;
}
```

Here, the auto keyword causes the function to derive which type it's supposed to be dealing with and return the result accordingly. My first guess is that I might have to use templates; but the problem with templates is that I can't limit which types get inserted into the function, and I really REALLY don't want floating-point id numbers, char ids, let alone custom-defined ids. It's either string (might change to const char* tbh) or ints or else.

How can I create a generic conversion function like the one described above?

Comment: I believe you have a general design problem! Having a "generic" Manager class which can deal with all types are typically broken design. You user code must get a defined type so it can call a specific storage class. Calling a manager class, get "unknown" type and do a manual conversion sounds horrible to me! So I believe you ask for a XY Problem here!

Comment: And yet, it works! A manual conversion is indeed horrible, but a generic Manager class that manages not all types but those dictated is a requirement I have laid out for a central place to keep relevant resources.

Comment: @Klaus various cross-cutting concerns lead to a single function returning heterogeneous types. Deserialization is a good example, as is memory management. (Of course, you're right that any class called "Manager" is to be viewed with the utmost suspicion and revulsion.)

Comment: @Sneftel Deserialization is good example where you expect a know type! If you have a data base or file with useful content your program must know which type the data has. No program can deal with unknown types. Maybe you have no idea in which order the data is recorded and the presentation in the program is something like "Infopackage". But the "Infopackage" itself knows the type and do never any kind of manual conversion. And all Infopackage types are related and have a common interface. Maybe something like a "process"-method or something else. Manual conversion of unrelated types is broken!

Comment: @Poriferous ` I have laid out for a central place to keep relevant resources` Exactly that is your broken design. `dictated is a requirement`. That is not a requirement, it is a solution and yes, a bad one. Think again what is really required and how it can be solved without braking the type safety of your language.

Comment: We can debate this; we clearly have two different philosophies here. Being a pragmatist, I would go for a resource manager to have any resource kept centrally. It's better than having a SpriteManager, MeshManager, TextureManager and all sorts. A long time ago I used to handle renderable objects in a simliar way and trust me the results were not effective. Essentially having multiple renderers and managers made maintenance a hell-scheme. Although your idea is theoretically correct, it's not practical or realistic for even forethought implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution to my question. I created a macro:

```
#define convert(type, func) dynamic_cast<type>(func)
```

Extremely generic and code-neutral which allows types to be dynamic_casted from the return type of the function. It also allows for doing checks:

```
if (!convert(ShaderProgram*, rm::get("skyboxShader")))
    cerr << "Conversion unsuccessful!" << endl;
else cout << "Conversion successful!" << endl;
```

I hope my solution will help people who search for questions similar of this kind. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at using [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast)?  If the conversion fails with `dynamic_cast` the the pointer will be set to `nullptr`.  So you could either write overloads for each type or you could write a template function where you pass the the type you want to convert to as well as the string or id and if the conversion succeeds or fails return `true` or `false`.

```
template<typename T>
bool Renderer::getResource(T*& type, const std::string &name)
{
    type = dynamic_cast<decltype(std::remove_reference<decltype(T)>::type)>(rm::get(name));
    if (type == nullptr)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why not just return the type? If the type is nullptr then it implies the conversion wasn't a success, which is what the logic expresses herein.

Comment: @poriferous that way you could just call the function in an if statement.  You could return the pointer if you like that better

Comment: I think there's also a syntax error with your code because one of the `<`s are not resolved.

Comment: @poriferous yes there were a couple of syntax errors.  Should be fixed now

Comment: Attempting to compile your code throws `error: argument to decltype must be an expression` and `error: template argument 1 is invalid`.

Comment: @Poriferous Can you provide an [mcve] and post it to http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/ ?  Then I can tell if it is something from my code.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I did not like the idea of a typeless storage, but maybe you find that basic program as a start point. There are a lot of things which must be beautified, but some work must remain :-)

Again: It is a design failure to solve something in that way!

In addition to your example code this solution provides a minimum of safety while checking for the stored type while recall the element. But this solution needs rtti an this is not available on all platforms.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

class ResourcePointerStorage
{
    private:
        std::map< const std::string, std::pair<void*, const std::type_info*>> storage;

    public:
        bool Get(const std::string& id, std::pair<void*, const std::type_info*>& ptr )
        {
            auto it= storage.find( id );
            if ( it==storage.end() ) return false;
            ptr= it->second;
            return true;
        }

        bool Put( const std::string& id, void* ptr, const std::type_info* ti)
        {
            storage[id]=make_pair(ptr, ti);
        }
};

template < typename T>
bool Get(ResourcePointerStorage& rm, const std::string& id, T** ptr) 
{
    std::pair<void*, const std::type_info*> p;

    if ( rm.Get( id,p ))
    {
        if ( *p.second != typeid(T)) { return false; }
        *ptr= static_cast<T*>(p.first);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

template < typename T>
void Put( ResourcePointerStorage& rm, const std::string& id, T *ptr)
{
    rm.Put( id, ptr, &typeid(T) ); 
}

class Car
{
    private:
        int i;

    public:
        Car(int _i):i(_i){}
        void Print() { std::cout << "A car " << i << std::endl; }
};

class Animal
{
    private:
        double d;

    public:
        Animal( double _d):d(_d) {}
        void Show() { std::cout << "An animal " << d << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    ResourcePointerStorage store;

    Put( store, "A1", new Animal(1.1) );
    Put( store, "A2", new Animal(2.2) );
    Put( store, "C1", new Car(3) );

    Animal *an;
    Car *car;

    if ( Get(store, "A1", &an)) { an->Show(); } else { std::cout << "Error" << std::endl; }
    if ( Get(store, "A2", &an)) { an->Show(); } else { std::cout << "Error" << std::endl; }
    if ( Get(store, "C1", &car)) { car->Print(); } else { std::cout << "Error" << std::endl; }

    // not stored object
    if ( Get(store, "XX", &an)) { } else { std::cout << "Expected false condition" << std::endl; }

    // false type
    if ( Get(store, "A1", &car)) { } else { std::cout << "Expected false condition" << std::endl; }
};
```

Comment: Your solution may be adequate but it's a missing a vital requirement: class types must be derived of type `Resource`. The ResourceManager I have doesn't work with non-Resource types. But, you very much created a generic manager class able to load any class.

Comment: @Poriferous You wrote that your classes are "unrelated". If they are ralated, you can replace the typinfo things to dynamic cast. Thats quite simple.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` is available on Windows and Mac, and I'm using Linux for primary development. The means of being able to dynamic_cast between Resource and a derivative thereof is only as simple as I want it to be. I do not intend to over-complicate matters any further, but I appreciate your solution.

Comment: @Poriferous Dynamic_cast is not related to the underlaying OS at all! It is only related that your compiler supports it on your plattform. It is always supported if RTTI is available which is true for most systems/compilers/platforms, especially for linux ones. OK, for 8bit AVR it is not :-)

Comment: When it comes to decisions such as these, I prefer to be realistic as to what the software is used for on which platforms. I doubt an OpenGL program could even remotely run on an 8bit AVR.